# Cursor difference with "Esc" and "Ctrl + O"

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, normal-mode

Say I have a session like this:

```
Sunday|Monday
```

Where `|` is the cursor in insert mode. If I press `Esc`, I get this:

```
Sunda█Monday
```

but I want this:

```
Sunday█onday
```

As I want to select the second "word", and if I go into visual mode, the `y`
will be part of the selection. I found that I can use `Ctrl + O` instead of
`Esc` and the cursor is correct, but it only allows one command and goes back
into insert mode. I want to stay in normal mode.

Is some key available for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. Control-C effectively cancels any pending mode and takes you into Normal in the current cursor position. Of course, you can create some mapping if you want.

To make things working also for the last character on line, make sure you have `:set ve=all` or `:set ve=onemore` in your vimrc. Or use <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>.

Comment: This is great. For some reason Vim has `i` and `a` (before and after), but only `Esc` (before). So this is a good workaround

Answer (score 3):

This is regular vi compatible behaviour. After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> the cursor is always moved one character back. I believe the reason is the following: If the cursor in insert mode is at the end of the entered text and you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, there is no text on which to place the cursor, therefore it is moved back to the last entered character. The one exception to this rule is, if the cursor is on the start of the line, in which case it obviously cannot be moved to the left and will be placed on an empty cell (press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> on it and notice the `NUL` result, which basically means there is no character)

If you don't want that behavior, I would suggest to map it to a behavior that you want, e.g.

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <esc> col('.')>1&&col('$')<col('.')?'<esc>l':'<esc>'
```

This uses an [expression mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-expression) that checks whether the cursor is either after column 1 or before the last column in the current row and only in those cases will try to move the cursor after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode back to the character it was in insert mode.

Slightly related, you might want to also allow to put the cursor after the last character. This can be done using `:set ve=onemore`. In that case, you do not need the condition `&&col('$')<col('.')` above and you can skip that.