# How to delete backwards till whitespace in Insert mode?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings

Hope you're doing well.

Input:

```js
let firstDate = src[0][0]|.toString();
                         ^
                         cursor in Insert mode
```

Desired output:

```js
let firstDate = |.toString();
                ^
              cursor in Insert mode
```

So deleting `src[0][0]`. Currently I always spam `<C-w>` (in this case 6 times).

I found a [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27770/how-can-i-delete-whitespace-backwards-until-end-of-previous-word) with the solution being, in Normal mode, `cT<space>`. The problem is that after entering Normal mode, the cursor is here:

```js
let firstDate = src[0][0].toString();
                        ^
                        cursor in Normal mode
```

The result after `jkcT<space>` (`jk` is my remap to escape Insert mode)

```js
let firstDate = |].toString();
                ^
                cursor in Insert mode
```

It leaves the `]` behind, which is not what I want.

Also, is there any way I can do so without leaving Insert mode? I rarely use `<C-U>` so any remapping is fine with me too. Remapping with `<C-b>` in Insert mode seems appropriate. I'm open to use any vim/neovim plugin as well.

I thought I found the solution in [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429173/delete-backwards-contiguous-whitespace-or-contiguous-non-whitespace-upto-beginni) but the solution still requires 6 `<C-b>` to delete till previous whitespace.

Thank you!

Comment: In your second example, you're going from insert mode to normal mode and this moves the cursor to the left. You don't need to do that.  If you're going to change something, stay as much as you can in normal mode. Therefore, I would immediately find the dot `f.` or `F.` depending on direction and type `dT<space>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (see [`:help i_CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O)) allows you to perform a single Normal mode command from Insert mode and automatically return to Insert mode after it is executed.

As Robert Smith suggested, I would propose `<C-o>dT<Space>`:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>

You can also use the [`B`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#B) motion to move to the beginning of the current [WORD](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#WORD), which is delimited by whitespace.

So:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Awesome! Works flawlessly. It's interesting to learn the [Cursor difference with "Esc" and "Ctrl + O"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/cursor-difference-with-esc-and-ctrl-o).